# Always redirect me to admin.php

Tags: php, if-statement

[duplicate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472800/correct-syntax-for-if-elseif-statment) that was the question i asked before and its closed now. i m asking that my login.php always redirect me to admin.php whatever the user will log on it redirected to admin.php how to prevent this on that same code? Help me please

Comment: Would "learn the language" be an answer?

Comment: @Bibek Subedi all the codes are given  at above link

Comment: if($admin){ always return TRUE; so find  how it happen?

Comment: @Irantha i defined the admin **$admin="abc@xyz.com";**

Comment: if this is always assigned as $admin="abc@xyz.com"; then if($admin){ always return true; so u will redirect to admin.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending something to the browser with `echo"Your Login Name or Password is invalid";` does not make any sense before calling `header("location: invalid.html");` because you can't send header information *after* you send payload.

You should remove the `echo`-Line or the redirect will not work.

In addition to that, `session_register()` is deprecated by PHP 5.3 and got removed in 5.4. Just use `session_start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `!=$admin` to `!$admin`

```
<?php
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if(($count==1) && (!$admin)){
        session_register("myusername");
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;        
        header("location: welcome.php");
        exit();
    }elseif (($count==1) && ($admin)){
        header("location: admin.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo"Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
        header("location: invalid.html");
        exit();
    }       
?>
```

Comment: `if($count == 1)
{
  if($admin)
 {
    header("location: admin.php");
    exit();
 }
 else
 {
    session_register("myusername");
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;        
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit();
 }
}
else
{
    echo"Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    header("location: invalid.html");
    exit();
} 
}`





i am using this code it always redirect me to admin.php

Comment: Have checked the value of $count and $admin ??? echo it and check

Comment: can you please tell me how to check it and echo?

Comment: var_dump($admin,$count);

Comment: i am newbie please tell me where to use it?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: admin in \login.php on line 54

Notice: Undefined variable: count in \login.php on line 54
NULL NULL