# How do I stop WordPress redirecting to admin.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

When my contributors try to log in on my site mindthebleep.com/wp-login.php it redirects them to mindthebleep.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=bluehost#home & says "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." If they then go to mindthebleep.com/wp-admin/profile.php it suddenly shows they've successfully logged in. I think the problem is due to .htaccess based on what I've read, but can't be sure.

I have reviewed other answers [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561120/always-redirect-me-to-admin-php) but it doesn't seem to work & cannot find a solution on the internet. I tried implementing a customised log in page but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that:

#### 1. Using `login_redirect` hook

Add this code to your theme's `functions.php`

```php
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

        if ( in_array( 'contributor', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to their profile page

            return home_url().'/wp-admin/profile.php';
        }else{
            return $redirect_to;
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

You can check list of default user role in WordPress [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/)

#### 2. Using plugin

I found one `https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/`

Just install this plugin and set it up if you are unfamiliar with the code.

[image: Admin of login redirect plugin]